# Schedule a Post using a google blogger api v3

Tags: api, blogger

I am using below google blogger api v3 instruction and putting a publish date in future . The post status is showing always live why it's not showing scheduled.

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/publish

I tried with setting value status = "scheduled" using insert api
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert

But still no luck.

From web interface it's working fine. but using v3 api is not working.

Any help?

Comment: please specify the programming language in which you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Posts:insert reference](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert), try this approach:

1. Set isDraft = FALSE
2. Set publishDate

Let me know if that's how you want it.